# DataGridView and Record ID C#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I guess I need some clarification on how the (My)SqlDataAdapter works.  I have a DGV that I use to display one column from a MySQL table; however when I need to edit the record, I need most of the other fields and I do this in another winform.  So I guess I need some best practices advice:

Question 1:  When binding to the datasource: Do I need to select ALL the fields I want to edit in the form?

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM cusdata";
cusAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query,pppDB.sqlConn);         
cusAdapter.Fill(mainSet,"cusdata");
dgv_cusData.DataSource = mainSet.Tables["cusdata"]
```

Question 2:  I see a lot of info all over the web about selecting just the fields you want to display in the DGV but if I edit that data how does the adapter know exactly what record is being updated on the back-end??

I guess I am just a bit confused about the different approaches and I need some guidance.  I want a datagridview where I can display a single column (Customer Name).  I want to be able to edit the customer record in another form and have the DVG refreshed with the new information upon successful completion of the Database action.

I have given the best part of a weekend through today to find an article or blog or something that demonstrates EXACTLY that.  List-Form paradigm.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Thanks much to the community.

Answer (score 1):

by experience you should not select all the fields, rather select only the fields you need

```
Select CustId, CustName, CustAddress, CustPhone from cusdata
```

this will impact performance.

when you edit a data you can use the code below:

```
string connectionString = "[Put your connection string here]";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE cusdata SET CustName=@CustName, CustAddress=@CustAddress WHERE CustId=@CustId", conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustId", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", "Name Input");
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", "Address input");

            int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            //rows number of record got updated
        }
    }
```

this part of the code let you specify the fields and data you want to update in your table

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustId", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustName", "Name Input");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustAddress", "Address input");
```

Comment: a good article for the basic crud in C# http://lamahashim.blogspot.com/2010/04/c-read-insert-update-delete-from-sql.html

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do understand the basics of CRUD and how to send parametized queries to the back-end; however, I wish to handle everything by binding my data to a datagridview using a datatable and performing updates to the back-end using the SqlDataAdapter.  I need real world articles/examples on how this is accomplished by others.